# OpenShift: "Failed to execute control start" on node application

Tags: linux, node.js, openshift

I realize in advance this is kind of a vague question, but I'm stumped as to what else I can try here...

I've been going through other SO questions and following their recommendations but so far nothing has solved my issue yet.

Here's the specific error I'm getting.

```
Stopping NodeJS cartridge
Fri Jul 10 2015 10:36:28 GMT-0400 (EDT): Stopping application 'appname' ...
Fri Jul 10 2015 10:36:29 GMT-0400 (EDT): Stopped Node application 'appname'

Starting NodeJS cartridge
Fri Jul 10 2015 10:36:30 GMT-0400 (EDT): Starting application 'appname' ...

Waiting for application port (8080) become available ...

Application 'appname' failed to start (port 8080 not available)

Failed to execute: 'control restart' for /var/lib/openshift/MYID/nodejs
```

My `package.json` file is up to date will all my dependencies, has the `scripts: { start: 'node server.js' }` property and yet I'm still getting this error.

If I SSH in and go to my `current/repo` directory and run `node server.js` it works fine. However, I can't just use `screen` to run it in the background forever.

I've also tried for stopping and restarting, git pushing, and restarting through the browser. I'm stumped as to what else I can try to get my (very simple) node application running on OpenShift.

Any suggestions are much appreciated.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For an OpenShift Node app you need to specify the start script as: `main: "server.js"` instead of using `scripts`. This is due to the way Node applications are started on OpenShift using [node-supervisor](https://github.com/petruisfan/node-supervisor).

Comment: Well, thanks to your comment I took a double look at my `package.json` and instead of a period in the filename under `main` I had a comma. *facepalm* Thanks!

Comment: Also, there might be some syntax error in other files that are required with the start. I had an error in a sub file and couldn't make the app start until I fixed the other file.

Answer (score 12):

**OpenShift Node apps** require you to give the configuration to start your app in **package.json** under **main** and **scripts.start**:

```
"scripts": {
     "start": "node server.js"
  },
"main": "server.js"
```

Further it also requires to give it **IP** and **PORT** provided by your node environment through environment variables:

```
for PORT Number       process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_PORT
for IP                process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_IP
```

If these variables not used in app , it shows error which looks like:

```
Waiting for application port (8080) become available ...
Application 'appname' failed to start (port 8080 not available)
```

Here is an example to show how to use these environment variables in your node app(from source):

```
var server_port = process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_PORT || 8080
var server_ip_address = process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_IP || '127.0.0.1'

server.listen(server_port, server_ip_address, function () {
console.log( "Listening on " + server_ip_address + ", server_port " + port )
});
```

Source: https://blog.openshift.com/run-your-nodejs-projects-on-openshift-in-two-simple-steps/

Related Post: [Application 'appname' failed to start (port 8080 not available) on open shift node app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31358992/application-appname-failed-to-start-port-8080-not-available-on-open-shift-no)

Comment: Also don't forget to use a { and a } around the json-snippet, else it won't compile.