# openshift application 'nodejs' failed to start (port 8080 not available)

Tags: node.js, openshift, ports

I read the instructions [here](https://blog.openshift.com/run-your-nodejs-projects-on-openshift-in-two-simple-steps/) to configure my nodejs application to run on openshift. For

> Step 2: Read Configuration Details from the System Environment

I basically copied and pasted the code replacing `Server` with `http`

```
// listening on the port

var server_port = process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_PORT || 8080;
var server_ip_address = process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_IP || '127.0.0.1';

http.listen(server_port, server_ip_address, function () {
  console.log( "Listening on " + server_ip_address + ", port " + server_port );
});
```

But when I enter the command `git push`, I get the following errors on my command prompt.

[image]

What does it mean

```
Application 'nodejs' failed to start (port 8080 not available)
```

Comment: I think you have already run your app there. Can you try to access your site?

Comment: it's giving me the 503 Service temporarily unavailable error when I try to access my site

Comment: I would start from checking log on your server.

Comment: I tried, rhc ssh is the command used to ssh into my instance, but I'm not able to access the logs afterwards

Comment: have you tried this? https://developers.openshift.com/en/managing-log-files.html

Comment: I checked the logs, it was pretty stupid actually.....a couple of variables not being defined...

Comment: try this command for know where is real error is `rhc tail -a appName`

Answer (score 1):

It means that some other process using port `8080`. `8080` is conventionally used for debugging trying using another port

Comment: it's trying to use port 8080 no matter what, how would I force it to use another port?

Comment: Try checking out what's running on `http://localhost:8080` if nothing works change `server_port = 3000`

Comment: the application isn't meant to run on localhost, I haven't installed any of my modules here, I push the code to the openshift server and it's supposed to install all my dependencies during the buildphase

Comment: This might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31358992/application-appname-failed-to-start-port-8080-not-available-on-open-shift-no

Answer (score 0):

Try this (considering from the snapshot you are on Windows),

```
netstat -anbo
```

This will show you all the ports currently in use on your system along with the executable and the process ID which has acquired that socket. Now simply check if your port 8080 is occupied by that process and kill it.

Comment: It says the requested operation requires elevation, nd I'm not trying to run this application on my system, it's supposed to run remotely. That's the problem

Comment: Run your `cmd` as administrator. Can you do that?

Comment: I don't really understand. why that would make a difference, I'm trying to run my application remotely, not locally

Comment: Not your cmd. The cmd on the remote system.

Comment: rhc ssh is the command used to ssh into my gear, I'm running. my application on openshift

Comment: I'm not sure if I can "run as administrator" on the remote system,