# Not able to start node server

Tags: openshift, openshift-cartridge

I am getting the following error when I try to start the server manually or from command prompt.

Stopping NodeJS cartridge

Sun Dec 20 2015 10:29:20 GMT-0500 (EST): Stopping application 'nodejs' ...

Sun Dec 20 2015 10:29:20 GMT-0500 (EST): Stopped Node application 'nodejs'

Starting NodeJS cartridge

Sun Dec 20 2015 10:29:21 GMT-0500 (EST): Starting application 'nodejs' ...

Waiting for application port (8080) become available ...

Application 'nodejs' failed to start (port 8080 not available)

Failed to execute: 'control restart' for /var/lib/openshift/5671bca50c1e66a111000114/nodejs

Please provide any solution. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try checking your logs for any errors in your app. You can either tail all logs by `rhc tail <yourApp>` or ssh into your app `rhs ssh <yourApp>` and checking logs in `~/app-root/logs/`.

Comment: Possible solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31343987/openshift-failed-to-execute-control-start-on-node-application/33168200#33168200