# Failed to connect to port 8080 error when using socket.io and node.js on openshift even when port 8000 specified

Tags: javascript, node.js, git, openshift

so I was working on a small node.js app and tried to host it on openshift. When I tried to do so and uploaded all of my files using git, It failed to connect to the port "8080". How can I stop this error?
Here is my Java code:

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);

var socket = io.connect('http://mattandjeffchat-appdevthing.rhcloud.com:8000/',{'forceNew':true });
http.listen(3000, function(){
 console.log('listening on *:3000');
 });
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

app.get('/', function(req, res){
 res.sendfile('index.html');
  });

io.on('connection', function(socket){
console.log('a user connected');
 });
```

Here is a picture of the error I get
[wont connect to 8080 server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dW0Ji.png)

Comment: You're listening on port `3000`?

Comment: I see my error, I'm quite new to node.js. I assume I should change it to 8000?

Comment: Yes, that's what makes NodeJS listen on port 8000.

Comment: I changed it and it is still not connecting.

Comment: It is still trying to connect to port 8080 after changing the 3000 to 8000.

Comment: This question is already answewed [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33168200/3690154)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When deploying app's on production environments this is what is recommended  as the port on environment you are deploying may not be openly available.

```
http.listen(process.env.PORT || 8080, "0.0.0.0", function () {
    console.log("App Started");
});
```